# Cannot access to a service exported from a module that is provided by a shared module when using ClientsModule.registerAsync()

Tags: typescript, microservices, nestjs, nestjs-config

The context is that I have created a shared config module that imports multiple config modules, each config modules are exporting their own service, the shared module exports each imported module, for the moment in my app i have the app module that import the shared config module and a auth module that imports the shared config module.

In the project i'm using nestjs microservices and i'm trying to register the `ClientsModule` with `registerAsync` method to access the auth config service in my auth module.

directory architecture :

```
/**
config/  
  - shared-config.module.ts
  - app/
     - app-config.service.ts
     - app-config.module.ts
  - auth/
     - auth-config.service.ts
     - auth-config.module.ts
  ... other config modules
- auth/
   - auth.module.ts
- app/
   - app.module.ts
*/
```

shared-config.module.ts :

```
@Module({
  imports: [AppConfigModule, MicroServiceAuthConfigModule, /* and other modules */],
  export: [AppConfigModule, MicroServiceAuthConfigModule, /* and other modules */]
})
export class SharedConfigModule {}
```

auth-config.module.ts :

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
           ... some config
        }),
    ],
    providers: [MicroServiceAuthConfigService],
    exports: [MicroServiceAuthConfigService],
})
export class MicroServiceAuthConfigModule {}
```

The problem is that i'm trying to use the `MicroServiceAuthConfigService` to create the `ClientsModule` in my `AuthModule`.

auth.module.ts :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedConfigModule,
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: 'AUTH_PACKAGE',
        inject: [MicroServiceAuthConfigService],
        useFactory: (authConfigService: MicroServiceAuthConfigService) => ({
          transport: Transport.GRPC,
          options: {
            url: authConfigService.url,
            package: authConfigService.package,
            protoPath: authConfigService.protoPath,
          },
        }),
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

app.module.ts :

```
@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, SharedConfigModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Because i have imported the SharedConfigModule, i should access to the MicroServiceAuthConfigService in the `useFactory` but instead i have the following error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AUTH_PACKAGE (?). Please make
> sure that the argument MicroServiceAuthConfigService at index [0] is
> available in the ClientsModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If MicroServiceAuthConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current ClientsModule?
> - If MicroServiceAuthConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ClientsModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing MicroServiceAuthConfigService */ ]   })

The strange thing is that in my app module i have injected the `SharedConfigModule` and in my file `main.ts` i'm using `app.get(MicroServiceAuthConfigService)` and it's working.

So what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ClientsModule.registerAsync` you need to add the `imports` that has the array containing the the module that exports the `MicroServiceAuthConfigService` provider. Looks like you specifically need

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedConfigModule,
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: 'AUTH_PACKAGE',
        imports: [MicroServiceAuthConfigModule],
        inject: [MicroServiceAuthConfigService],
        useFactory: (authConfigService: MicroServiceAuthConfigService) => ({
          transport: Transport.GRPC,
          options: {
            url: authConfigService.url,
            package: authConfigService.package,
            protoPath: authConfigService.protoPath,
          },
        }),
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I have directly imported `SharedConfigModule` in the `registerAsync` because i'm only using the `MicroServiceAuthConfigService` in the AuthModule but that's the right way